# Java Gmail API - Reading credentials from json file using Inputstream vs BufferedReader

Tags: java, gmail-api

Im trying to run my java application on Ubuntu server. I enter absolute path to read that file but it produces and error.

The code which is supposed to read that file is below.

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/home/dockeradmin/credentials.json";


InputStream in = application.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
```

And the error I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /home/dockeradmin/credentials.json
```

When I tried to read file with same path using BufferedReader everything worked perfectly.

Like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/home/dockeradmin/credentials.json")));
```

So my question is, what is the difference between these two and how could I solve my current problem?

Comment: do a ls on  your docker pod see where the file is being placed.   its not where you think it is.   or check the permissions on the file make sure the app can read it.

Comment: why not set CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH  as an env var`?

Comment: @DaImTo doesnt matter, it still wont work

Comment: @DaImTo also permissions are correct, -rw-rw-r--

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is that [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) is used to locate file on classpath and it can't be used for locating file on file system.

Answer (score 0):

This line caused trouble.

```
InputStream in = application.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
```

I fixed this by replacing that, with that

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
```